# connect to google cloud mysql using android studio app

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am doing a project which requires me to query google cloud mysql database to save, delete, retrieve and update data using app build in android studio.
I have been googling for quite some time, all the tutorials are using AppEngine. However in android studio 3.0+, there isn't any App Engine available anymore.
Please give advice / guidance on what should I do?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android Studio 3 doesn't support AppEngine anymore, you have **two options**:

1. Build your own custom backend (web service) to function as a layer that allows database consumption via the Android app. This will require more development effort than option 2.
2. Set up [**Firebase**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and use [its database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) instead.
   You will have to do a bit of research on getting Firebase up and running, but you wan't have to build a custom backend.

If using the Google Cloud MySQL database is a must, then you can't get around to foreseeing your own backend layer.

Comment: Hi, option 1 means running my own server? Is it possible that i put my database on google cloud and  i query from there? I need SQL database thus option 2 is not suitable for me.

Comment: It indeed means that you should provide a service that acts as a server for your Android app and as a client for the database. It can be hosted anywhere, as long as it's accessible for the Android app.

Comment: I see, i know how to run php script as server on localhost using xampp, can you explain to me how to make this public and accessible anywhere? Is it i need to purchase a domain? How can i host it online?

Comment: Note that I'm not that familiar with php. I recommend you use a cloud provider and follow their documentation to simplify the integration process. You also won't be needing a domain. Maybe you can stick with [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/php/)? If you have any specific php-related issues I suggest you post a new question.